# How to convert ndarray to a tuple of arrays?

Tags: python-3.x, tuples, numpy-ndarray

**Say for example if I have a ndarray(mp) like this:**

```
`mp =
 [[2.3980985828756736 6861 -1 6861]
 [2.4120089384661587 6862 -1 6862]
 [2.4235102880216637 6863 -1 6863]
 ...
 [1.0564918793423272 2418 2418 -1]
 [1.0562595999589373 2419 2419 -1]
 [1.0543968001562891 2420 2420 -1]]`
```

**I want the first two columns from mp and I want them to be converted like this**

```
the mp is 
 `(array([2.12734638, 2.13031872, 2.12896207, ..., 4.24341706, 3.71451699,
       3.24234188]), array([ 77795.,  77796.,  77797., ..., 111854.,  60951.,  60952.]))`
```

**How do I do that thanks in advance...**

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please ensure you read [How to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a code demonstrating an effort to solve the issue yourself (for that you may want to review suggestions on [reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can read about numpy indexing [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

for your example you can use:

```
mp = np.array(
 [[2.3980985828756736, 6861, -1, 6861],
 [2.4120089384661587, 6862, -1, 6862],
 [2.4235102880216637, 6863, -1, 6863],
 [1.0564918793423272, 2418, 2418, -1],
 [1.0562595999589373, 2419, 2419, -1],
 [1.0543968001562891, 2420, 2420, -1]])

print((mp[:, 0], mp[:, 1]))
```

**output:**

```
(array([2.39809858, 2.41200894, 2.42351029, 1.05649188, 1.0562596 ,
       1.0543968 ]), array([6861., 6862., 6863., 2418., 2419., 2420.]))
```